# Spring Boot @Converter always accessible with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a `Spring Boot` application which uses the following converter.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date> {

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
        if (entityValue != null) {
            return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date databaseValue) {
        if (databaseValue != null) {
            return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This converter is package private and works with an integration test annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. However when trying to start the application using the jar or the Maven `spring-boot:run` goal I get the following error:

```
2018-12-15 23:36:18.349 ERROR 1772 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [org.donorcalendar.persistence.LocalDatePersistenceConverter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.donorcalendar.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [org.donorcalendar.persistence.LocalDatePersistenceConverter]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.instantiateAttributeConverter(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition can not access a member of class org.donorcalendar.persistence.LocalDatePersistenceConverter with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.instantiateAttributeConverter(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

In fact I believe this error is the normal behavior, what I would like to understand is **why this converter is created and used correctly during my integration tests?**

Is the `@SpringBootTest` annotation making the converter being initiated in a different way that doesn't require it to be `public`? I already know how to solve the issue (just make the converter `public`), but I would like to understand why the code behaves differently during tests.

I would like to have end to end tests that runs as similar as possible to the real application. Unfortunately for this case I get a problem during application start up, but normal initialization and execution during test execution.

Could someone explain why this difference? I can provide more details on the application set up if necessary.

**My question is about the different behaviors when running the application and it's integration tests, I already know how to fix the error with the converter, so please don't answer that I just need to add the `public` modifier. I want to configure my tests in a way they would have the same behavior (and errors) as when the application is started normally, so I can be more confident on my end to end tests.**

Answer (score 0):

The error is due that you have LocalDatePersistenceConverter class with access modifier by default which is empty so Hibernate can't find it, so you need to put as public by following way:

```
 public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter....
```

On your tests is in package which access modifier doesn't have problem when starting up the application.

*References*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Just to be clear, I already knew that public would fix the startup issue. What I want is to understand why it's working on my integration test, could you elaborate on why this works during the tests? My tests and converters are in different packages and that doesn't seem to be the issue, these tests are meant to be end to end and I think the idea is to have spring fully starting the application and loading everything, close as possible to the real execution, I don't understand how the integration tests initialization is working differently to avoid this problem.

Comment: It's OK, so you need to provide the tests code in order to know the testing strategy that you are using. Perhaps you are using some database which doesn't use Hibernate.

Comment: You can see the whole project here: [link](https://github.com/taizel/donor-calendar). The class UserControllerIT is one example, but in summary is just a test annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`.